# Unittest's assertItemsEqual and unordered lists of unhashable objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-3.7

I have a container class I'm using to store items: 2 strings and a set. The
strings will be constant throughout the object's lifetime but the set will have
items added to it. Given this, I know the objects can't be hashed but the class
should (could?) provide `__eq__` so comparisons work on unit testing.

The problem I'm having is: most comparisons work, but it seems the lists have to
be sorted, otherwise the test fails, even though unittest documentation stating
that `assertItemsEqual` *"Test that sequence expected contains the same elements
as actual, regardless of their order. (...) It verifies if each element has the
same count in both sequences. It is the equivalent of
`assertEqual(sorted(expected), sorted(actual))` but it works with sequences of
unhashable objects as well."*.

This is part of a bigger project, the code below reproduces the issue (can point to the code on github if needed)

File `my_class.py`

```py
class MyClass(object):
    # Because locations can change, the object can't be hashable
    __hash__ = None

    def __init__(self, library, name, locations=None):
        self.library = str(library)
        self.name = str(name)
        self._locations = set()

        for filename, line_number, column_number in locations or []:
            self.addItem(filename, line_number, column_number)

    def addItem(self, filename, line_number, column_number):
        self._locations.add(
            (str(filename),
             str(line_number),
             str(column_number) if column_number is not None else None))

    @property
    def __eq_key__(self):
        return self.library, self.name, tuple(sorted(self._locations))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}.{}(library={}, name={}, locations={})'.format(
            __name__, self.__class__.__name__, repr(self.library),
            repr(self.name), repr(list(self._locations)))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Overrides the default implementation"""
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return self.__eq_key__ == other.__eq_key__
        return NotImplemented
```

File `test_my_class.py`

```py
import unittest2
import six

from my_class import MyClass

reference = MyClass(library='library',
                    name='name',
                    locations=[('filename', 4, None),
                               ('filename', 7, None),])

class TestMyClass(unittest2.TestCase):

    # This works
    def test_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            reference,
            MyClass(library='library', name='name',
                    locations=[('filename', 4, None),
                               ('filename', 7, None),]))

    # This works
    def test_not_equal(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(
            reference,
            MyClass(library='library', name='name'))

    # This works
    def test_ordered_list(self):
        self.assertItemsEqual(
            [MyClass(library='library', name='name'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_1', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2'),
            ],
            [MyClass(library='library', name='name'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_1', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2'),
            ])

    # Fails!
    def test_unordered_list(self):
        self.assertItemsEqual(
            [MyClass(library='library', name='name'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_1', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2'),
            ],
            [MyClass(library='library', name='name'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_1', name='name_0'),
             MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1'),
            ])

if six.PY3:
    TestMyClass.assertItemsEqual = TestMyClass.assertCountEqual

unittest2.main()
```

Running on Python 3 (3.7 to be exact) it works, but Python 2.7 it doesn't:

```
$ python2 test_my_class.py
...F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_unordered_list (__main__.TestMyClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_my_class.py", line 55, in test_unordered_list
    MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1'),
AssertionError: Sequences differ: [my_c[100 chars]name_0', locations=[]), my_class.MyClass(libra[164 chars]=[])] != [my_c[100 chars]name_2', locations=[]), my_class.MyClass(libra[164 chars]=[])]

First differing element 0:
my_class.MyClass(library='library', name='name', locations=[])
my_class.MyClass(library='library', name='name', locations=[])

  [my_class.MyClass(library='library', name='name', locations=[]),
+  my_class.MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2', locations=[]),
   my_class.MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_0', locations=[]),
   my_class.MyClass(library='lib_1', name='name_0', locations=[]),
-  my_class.MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1', locations=[]),
?                                                                ^

+  my_class.MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_1', locations=[])]
?                                                                ^

-  my_class.MyClass(library='lib_0', name='name_2', locations=[])]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://bugs.python.org/issue10242?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does look similar, although the exact example mentioned in the issue always seems to work over here. Since `assertItemsEqual` is not reliable in this case, I wrote a custom O(n**2) test that seems to work. Thanks again, I was starting to get angry at this, luckily it wasn't something stupid I did.